# linq query check GroupBy() for value

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following data object:

```
OrderId WarehouseId Sku         Dropship
========================================
630     1           ABC-123     Yes 
630     2           ABC-123     T            
630     3           ABC-123     null
630     1           XYZ-789         
630     2           XYZ-789     null             
630     3           XYZ-789
```

I need a linq query that gets the count of the number of items that are not dropship items. The dropship determination is:

`Dropship = false`: if the `Dropship` field is `null` or `empty` for a given `sku` at **all 3** `WarehouseId`. In the example above `sku XYZ-789` would not be considered a dropship item.

`Dropship = true`: if the `Dropship` field is `not null` or `not empty` for a given `sku` at **any one** of the 3 `WarehouseId`. In the example above `sku ABC-123` would be considered a dropship item.

With the following query I am expecting a result of `1`, but am getting `2`.

```
int dropshipItems = orderItems
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Dropship))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Sku)
    .Count();
```

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using? Is this LINQ to Objects? EF? LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Any reason you can't force `DropShip` to be a simple Boolean?

Comment: Are the "null" fields truly null or is it a string that contains the string "null"?  Are the apparently empty Dropships really empty, or do they contain whitespace?  And @BerinLoritsch is correct, dropship should likely be a boolean or  bit field.

Comment: I'm using linqpad that is querying an Oracle database, not sure what linq provider that is? And I know it seems obvious that `Dropship` should be a boolean, but I'm not able to change that.

Comment: Well if we could see any of the code, we'd probably be able to tell. Maybe someone with more LinqPad experience knows what it offers...

Comment: I think most likely the Dropship is not varchar but char and thus filled with spaces. Linq to (MS) SQL doesn't support `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but try adding `.Trim()` to `x.Dropship`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Dropship)` use `!(x.Dropship==null || x.Dropship.Equals(""))` there are some problems with `string.IsNullOrEmpty` in `LINQ to SQL`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought it's LINQ to SQL when had looked at his "Consider the following data object:"

Comment: Well "data object" could mean "in memory" or "in SQL but being fetched via EF, or Dapper, or NHibernate, or..." I'd always start off by asking for clarification....

Comment: @JonSkeet I do agree with you, will always ask in future, thanks

Comment: running the OPs code with in-memory object returns `1`, so you're probably on the right track here.

Comment: Apparently his LINQ to Oracle SQL in LINQPad supports `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` or he would have gotten an error rather than the wrong answer, as I did with LINQ to (MS) SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `.Select().Distinct().Count()` to using `.GroupBy().Count()` when you don't need a group, not sure which is more efficient.

```
int dropshipItems = orderItems
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Dropship.Trim()))
    .Select(x => x.Sku)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```